# Unable to prevent over posting using customer id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have simple MVC application .

In Edit operation

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(string CustomerId, [Bind(Include = "CustomerId,CompanyId,CompanyName,ContactName,ContactTitle,Address,City,Region,PostalCode,Country,Phone,Fax")] Customer customer)
{
    var user = db.Users.Find(CustomerId);
    if (user != null)
        TryUpdateModel(user);
    else
        return HttpNotFound();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

> But When I do F12 and change hidden field value of `CustomerId` it is taking changed `CustomerId` that should not be done ?

I want to prevent this over-posting of `CustomerId`.

1.If `CustomerId` is changed using F12 then throw an error.
2.If `CustomerId` is correct not tamper then simply update all values

I'm getting exception :

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Attaching an entity of type 'MVCDemo.Models.Customer' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.
```

Comment: Is this in regards to a user editing data?

Comment: Why do you have parameter `string CustomerId` when your `Customer` model also appears to have property `CustomerId`? You specify its to be included in the binding so what are you expecting?

Comment: Looks like we might need the try update model code as well for that exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are many ways to do this, the most simple that comes up in my mind will look like this.

1. Generate a `randomKey` (can be Guid or something else) store the `customerId` in `Session[randomKey] = customerId`, this is happening before you render the View containing the form.
2. In hidden field store `randomKey` and when you make a post on server side take `customerId` from `Session`, `customerId = Session[randomKey]`.

This way `customerId` will **never be on client side** and cannot be changed to post it on server.

**Notes:**

1. The user can change the `customerId` with F12, remember that the **user own the HTML** and he can make any change he want.
2. Maybe you can catch this change with javascript, but what happens if he disable the javascript and change the value?
3. Because the `randomKey` is stored in `Session`, the key has a **limited time life** and user cannot copy the key for a latter usage.

Comment: What happens if the user is editing 2 customers in 2 different tabs at the same time?

Comment: @StephenMuecke there is no problem becuase you store the `CustomerId` under a `randomKey` (that is generated every time when you render the Edit View). This means that you have a `randomKey` per `CustomerId`. Depends how you implement this, you can have multiple `randomKey` for same `CustomerId`, This way you prevent user to copy paste the randomKey and use it later.

Comment: so there is no direct way of doing instead comparing CustomerId ? I thought there must be some feature to prevent Excluded items

Comment: @ashu I don't think exist a feature like this because it's more likely to be coupled with the requirements of the application. In my solution you don't have to compare the Ids, you keep the Id on server side and send a *token* (instead the id) to user and when the edit is make the id will be retrived based on that *token*.

Answer (score 1):

One technique to prevent tampering of hidden fields to to include another hidden field containing a hash of the `CustomerId` value. Then in the POST method, you can compare the values and will know if its been tampered with.

[This article](http://blog.slatner.com/2010/01/20/SecuringFormValuesInASPNETMVC.aspx) discusses the technique including a custom html helper to generate the hidden input.

Comment: so there is no direct way of doing instead comparing CustomerId ? I thought there must be some feature to prevent Excluded items

Comment: You have specified the property in the `[Bind(Include=...)]` so it will be bound (and you need to include it anyway or you would never know the ID when you post - although I don't understand why you have included it twice)