# Form security in MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, razor

I have 2 forms in my project MVC razor C#

> View1: That shows all records. Clicking on particular record goes it
>   edit page.
>
> View2: That shows the selected record in a form for update purpose.

So when user submits the form...that goes to Controller...Controller Action method has a View Model parameter that has ID property getting populated from Hidden Field present in the View.

**There is tendency that somebody intentionally change the ID in html through  Inspect Element of Browser and data can go to some wrong record.**

One way to fix this issue is to pass Encrypted Value from the View Model. But still user can swap the encrypted value from another record and can put that Encrypted ID value in another record in html through Inspect Element before they submit the form.

I hope I clarified the issue. Still there is any issue while reading, Kindly let me know to clarify again.

Kindly suggest the solution.

Comment: is there any kind of authorization on view1? i.e. is a user able to edit any record, or are they only presented with a list of records which they are able to edit?

Comment: you should keep ID property in session or server side cookies instead if client side.

Comment: Encrypting it wont help. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531661/unable-to-prevent-over-posting-using-customer-id/29532001#29532001) for one technique of preventing a malicious user changing the hidden input value.

Comment: @AmitSoni: Really? No offense, but that's just categorically wrong. First, there's no such thing as "server side cookies". A cookie is inherently client-side. Second, out of all the ways you could possibly handle a situation like this, storing an id value in session doesn't even make the list.

Comment: @ChrisPratt sessions are server side cookies..  if we says server side cookies, that's means session.

Comment: Sorry, nope. You and your pals may have a colloquialism that you share, but there's no such thing as "server-side cookies". There's cookies and sessions.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is to *not* post the id. Instead, make the id part of the URL, then if it's changed an entirely different resource is in play:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, Foo model)
{
    var foo = db.Foos.Find(id);
    if (foo == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // map values from model (posted data) to instance from DB
        db.Entry(foo).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: There is one confusion in this post. Imagine that the record for ID = 1 is going to be updated. but user intentionally set ID = 3 in the html through Inspect Element of Browser. So, ID will never will null in Post Action method. but I want update for only and only ID = 1. How can I make this sure ?

Comment: That's the point. It doesn't matter what the user sets in the form, because the only id that will ever be changed is that which is in the URL. You just totally ignore any submitted value for `ID`; you don't even need a hidden input for it.

Comment: Just one trap to be aware of - if the model property is named `ID` (the same as the parameter) and a hidden input was included, and a malicious user altered it, then the value of the parameter would be the altered value (the `DefaultModelBinder` reads values form form data before route values) so best not to include any hidden input.

Comment: In that case , How can I post the value from View to Controller ?

Comment: You don't need to, and in fact *shouldn't*. That's the point. When you're editing an existing entity, the id shouldn't even be on the form. It shouldn't be changed, so don't provide a vector for it to be changed.